# Add Fabric.framework with theos

Tags: xcode, frameworks, hook, twitter-fabric, theos

Can you help me add Fabric.framework to theos. I want to use this Framework to folow logs or crash my tweak from Farbic.

Add CoreMotion Framework With Theos Add Twitter.framework to Theos on iPhone

Copy Fabric framework to Xcode in your Mac. /Users/iavtech/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
add in makefile nameapphook_FRAMEWORKS = nameframework
Call header normal in your code it's work for me.
But Fabric just work when app or daemon have Info.plist it is added some key of Fabric. So when hook into daemon don't have Info.plist => App crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you even linked some relevant Q&As, have you tried anything? If so what issues came up?

Comment: Fabric.framework is not a framework suport by Xcode. So, i can't add this framework in to my tweak.
Error:   Linking tweak wifid...
ld: framework not found Fabric
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)